# Random Variable that takes one one of two numbers with a probability in R

Tags: r

I have a problem in my coding. Apologies but I am new, so this may be a simple answer. I have searched many, many forums and tried reading through books on R but I cannot figure out this problem. I want to have a formula that outputs at random 1 of two numbers with a given probability. For example, it would need to out put 10 or 20 with the probabilities tied to them 30% or 60% respectively. It seems like every random variable function built in has a limitation. Thank you.

Comment: 30%+60%=90%. What do you want the other 10% of the time? You can use the `sample()` function with the `prob=` parameter to specify the probabilities. What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`runif`](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/Uniform.html) for that.

`if (runif(1) < 0.3) { print(10) } else { print(20) }`

If you want to test if this actually works you could test it easily:

```
set.seed(42)

a <- vector()

for (i in 1:100){
  if(runif(1) < 0.3){
    a[i] <- 10
  } else {
    a[i] <- 20}
}

mean(a)
```

In this case I'd expect the mean of `a` to be approximately 17 (in this case it is 17.2).

I'm not sure why you stated that you want probabilities of 30% and 60% in the OP, I assume that's a typo - but if I misread your statement please feel free to add a comment.

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to solve the problem. It's best to preallocate vectors to the correct length at the start rather than grow them over time and it's better to grab a bunch of random variables at once rather than repeatedly requesting values. You could get the same answer with just `mean(ifelse(runif(100) < 0.3, 10, 20))`

Comment: @mrflick: true, your approach is better, since it is more efficient and 'cleaner' (and `base::sample()` as you stated in your comment above even more so).  If you would put that into an answer I'd upvote it!